# Get the dropped object using IDropHandler.OnDrop

Tags: unity, c#, gui

In Canvas, I drag some UI objects to a panel using this code:

```
public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
   Vector3 screenPoint = Input.mousePosition;
   screenPoint.z = 10.0f;
   Item2Drag.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPoint);
}
```

But what I can't figure out is when I dropped an object on the panel, how can I get the gameObject which has been dropped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

I can get it by `eventData.pointerDrag` from OnDrop function.

```
public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
{
   GameObject droppedObject = eventData.pointerDrag;
}
```